# Django Creating Item Defaults when being Created Model not working

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to set a default variation for each item created to be Small medium and large

I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'all'` I tried fixing it but other errors show up, what is the best way if this code is not correct to create 3 sizes default for every item created I don't have a category class just an option which I think might be causing the problem

Here is the model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update_defaults = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')


VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size', 'size',),
    ('color', 'color',),
    ('package', 'package'),
)

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = VariationManager()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def item_defaults(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.update_defaults:
        categories = instance.category.all()
        for cat in categories:
            small_size = Variation.object.get_or_create(
                product=instance, category='size', title='Small')
            medium_size = Variation.object.get_or_create(
                product=instance, category='size', title='Medium')
            large_size = Variation.object.get_or_create(
                product=instance, category='size', title='Large')

        instance.update_defaults = False
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(item_defaults, sender=Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

this part you need to correct

```
def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(active=True)
```

and you need to over-ride the default objects, this part need be added at the bottom of variation model

```
............
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
objects = VariationManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: for the item_defaults function ? Also ```objects = VariationManager()``` is available in class variations

Comment: Sorry, but Could you be more specific to where these updates should be made?  Regarding the first part  ` def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(active=True)` it should be below the variation manager and the second part also in the variation manager?